# Closing tabs on click in Android

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I'm writing an application that creates multiple tabs I want the user to have the option to close it  when pressing on a button the same way closing tabs in brewer by pressing the little x in the corner 
but I want only one tab to close and the rest stays

here is my code

```
    TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();

    TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1");

    TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
    spec2.setIndicator("Tab 2");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);


    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);
```

I want Tab2 to close when the user press on the button, my problem is how to remove the tab from TabHost not adding a listener to the button

is there a way to do that? I found a function which removes everything and I do not want that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following on button event

```
TabHost  tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but I also had to add `tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);` tv is the textview inside my tab

Answer (score 0):

This one will help you, very easy one for far i found.

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().removeView(tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2));
```

In addition, these are the available functionality that you can use to remove individual tabs

- removeView(View view)
- removeViewAt(int index)
- removeViewInLayout(View view)

Hope it helps!

Comment: If you look at the demo app for ActionBarSherlock there is an example that adds and removes tabs. This will probably give you an idea of how to remove tabs programmatically (even without ABS).

Comment: Ali i guess he didn't use Sherlock !

Comment: Even if he didn't the api is very similar, it should provide insight on what to do.